# Spring Security - Roles not accessible in HttpServletRequest unless specified via mappableAuthorities

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot web application that is run on a Tomcat application server and authenticates against a third party IdP.

We currently do role based authentication in a number of our apps using `<security-role>` and `<security-constraint>` in a  `web.xml`, and it works properly.

Now, attempting to use Spring Security, I have added the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] publicPaths = /*get public paths from properties*/
        String[] authorizedPaths = /*get authorized paths from properties*/
        String[] authorizedRoles = /*get authorized roles from properties*/

        http.csrf().disable()
                .jee()
                .mappableAuthorities(authorizedRoles)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicPaths).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(authorizedPaths).hasAnyRole(authorizedRoles)
                .and()
                .logout().disable()
        ;
    }

}
```

The `authorizedRoles` in the config above are roles that are authorized to access this application. However, there are other manual checks in the app that just call `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` to determine if a user has a certain role. Before using Spring Security, that call would return `true` if that user had that role in the original request. After adding Spring Boot, that call only returns `true` if the role is one of those passed to `.mappableAuthorities()` in the example above. The roles that are checked via `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` are stored in a database and can be updated often, so passing them to `.mappableAuthorities()` when the application loads is not feasible.

So, to get to the point of my question, it seems like Spring Security is modifying the original `HttpServletRequest` and taking out any roles that are not contained in the `authorizedRoles` passed to `.mappableAuthorities()`.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, or possibly pass some kind of wildcard to `.mappableAuthorities()`, so that you don't have to know all roles on application startup for them to be accessible via a call to `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()`? I've been looking at Spring Security documentation for hours and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can see only mapped roles, because [`SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.html) wraps the `HttpServletRequest`:

> A Filter which populates the ServletRequest with a request wrapper which implements the servlet API security methods.

It uses [`SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html) to implement the servlet API security methods:

> A Spring Security-aware `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, which uses the `SecurityContext`-defined `Authentication` object to implement the servlet API security methods:
>
> - `getUserPrincipal()`
> - `isUserInRole(String)`
> - `HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteUser()`.

To customize the roles mapping see [`J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/j2ee/J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.html):

> Implementation of AuthenticationDetailsSource which converts the user's J2EE roles (as obtained by calling `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String)`) into `GrantedAuthority`s and stores these in the authentication details object.

It uses a [`MappableAttributesRetriever`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/MappableAttributesRetriever.html) to get the mappable roles:

> Interface to be implemented by classes that can retrieve a list of mappable security attribute strings (for example the list of all available J2EE roles in a web or EJB application).

You could write your own [`MappableAttributesRetriever`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/MappableAttributesRetriever.html) which loads the mappable roles from your database.

Or you can use [`WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/j2ee/WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever.html), which retrieves the roles from `web.xml`:

> This `MappableAttributesRetriever` implementation reads the list of defined J2EE roles from a web.xml file and returns these from `getMappableAttributes()`.

Comment: But that won't solve the issue. The `MappableAttributesRetriever` or `WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever` still needs the list of all mappable roles, whether it comes from the database or wherever. I want it to account for all roles in the request, no matter what they are. With our other applications, I believe this is achieved by specifying the `allRolesMode` attribute on the `<Realm>` tag in the tomcat `server.xml`.

Comment: That is not possible, [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) has no method to retrieve the roles, that's the reason, why Spring Security needs such a mapping. It is only possible to ask with `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole` if a particular role is available. If you find a way to get all roles from `HttpServletRequest`, you can use this way in your own `MappableAttributesRetriever`.